# How can I implemente Save/Discard functionality with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mvvm

I have a working WPF app using MVVM pattern in which the ViewModel calls Queries that do all the save/update/get/delete stuff. I did this because it's easy to modify that queries to swap storage system, for example.

The app is working fine if the data is stored/deleted on the fly but the client wants a Save button so I have to remember (or Nhibernate) which changes are made. I don't want to have a session open long time so I don't know best way to do it. Do you know any pattern/architecture that would work?

Comment: You mean lazynes of NHibernate or some internal cache ? There's too many ways to implement it....

Comment: It's as my app would need something to remember which table columns has been deleted, added or modified, and then at the end flush or not this changes. The problem is that I don't use Nhibernate in ViewModel but in external queries, which retrieve objects to me or save them to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me for a simple app:

- open session for viewmodel
- if not use a transaction then Flushmode.Never (prevents queries from flushing)
- use id generator which generates client side ids (hilo, guidcomb,...)
- dont use Flush after the CRUD
- check `session.IsDirty` to enable savebutton
- if save -> flush() or commit
- if cancel -> Dispose session or rollback

NH will then send all actions at the end on flush

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that but is not a problem to have a session open for so long? I mean users can open my app and keep it open for hours doing changes or not.

Comment: holding the session open does not mean holding the database connection open, so it's safe to use it even for longer time. Transactions in contrary should be as short as possible. I took the advice from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx

Comment: Okey, that seems great to me as I was concerned about having it open for a while.